# Comparing grouped values in a database table with an associative array

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database, associative-array

I have three PHP arrays which all have the same two keys: `pId` and `name`. The name of the arrays are `added`, `deleted` & `updated`.

The table I want to compare with looks like this:

```
id
relationId
pId
name
changeType
```

The rows are grouped by the relationId and there may be multiple pId & name pairs per relationId. `changeType` can be either `added`, `deleted` or `updated`.

What I want is to be able to run a single query that checks if a group of `pId` & `name` pairs (where the `changeType` matches the array name) that matches the three arrays exactly, exists in the table and return the `relationId`.

Is this possible?

---

Example

Table:

```
+--------+----------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
| **id** | **relationId** | **pId** |    **name**   | **changeType** |
+--------+----------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
|    1   |        1       |    1    |     Smith     |      added     |
+--------+----------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
|    2   |        1       |    2    |      John     |     updated    |
+--------+----------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
|    3   |        1       |    3    |     Dexter    |     deleted    |
+--------+----------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
|    4   |        1       |    4    |   Heisenberg  |      added     |
+--------+----------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
|    5   |        2       |    4    |   Heisenberg  |      added     |
+--------+----------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
|    6   |        2       |    3    |     Dexter    |     updated    |
+--------+----------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
|    7   |        2       |    3    | Dexter Morgan |     updated    |
+--------+----------------+---------+---------------+----------------+
```

PHP Array:

```
$added = array(
 [1] = array(
    pId => 4,
    name => 'Heisenberg'
 ) 
)

$deleted = array(
 //Empty
)

$updated = array(
 [1] = array(
    pId => 3,
    name => 'Dexter'
 )
 [2] = array(
    pId => 3,
    name => 'Dexter Morgan'
 ) 
)
```

When querying using this array the returned relationId should be 2.

Comment: This is a little bit abstract. Could you show some code and some sample data?

Comment: Yeah, it's quite hard to explain but I posted an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by comparing an imploded string from the arrays with `GROUP_CONCAT` on the table. Since you can't normally use `GROUP_CONCAT` in the `WHERE` clause I had to do a workaround with the `FROM` clause.

```
<?php
    $s = '';
    foreach($updated as $u){
        $s .= $u['pId'] . $u['name'] . 'updated,';
    }
    foreach($deleted as $d){
        $s .= $d['pId'] . $d['name'] . 'deleted,';
    }
    foreach($added as $a){
        $s .= $a['pId'] . $a['name'] . 'added,';
    }

    //remove last comma
    $s = rtrim($s, ',');

    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("
    SELECT 
        relationId
        FROM (
            SELECT
                relationId, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(pId, name, changeType ORDER BY changeType DESC, id ASC) AS personConcat
            FROM 
                persons
            GROUP BY relationId
        ) x
        WHERE personConcat = ?
    ");

    $stmt -> bind_param('s', $s);
    $stmt -> execute();
?>
```